# python xlrd workflow with selenium

Tags: python, django

While run the code this error will be shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\QUALITY
>   LABS\workspace\magic\example.py", line 2, in  import xlrd
>   File "C:\Python34\xlrd.py", line 4, in  wb =
>   xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\TRB 2014 Data','SPS1 demo
>   data.xlsx'))  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'open_workbook'

Please help me, I tried it in many ways: deleted `.pyc` files too.

Comment: Don't name your script `xlrd`, it "shadows" the real `xlrd` module.

Comment: i change  the xlrd name in sitepackages still i got that issue please give me the full explanation that is easy for me,